# Initialize String List property on User Control

Tags: asp.net, collections, properties, user-controls

How to initialize a `List<string>` property on a User Control in ASPX ?

For `List<string> MyList` I want to initalize it like:

```
<uc:MyUserControl>
    <MyList>
         <String>X</String>
         <String>Y</String>
    </MyList>
</uc:MyUserControl>
```

Or like:

```
<uc:MyUserControl MyList="X,Y" />
```

I would like to know the solution to both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by other way.

Add other property of type string, you can name it is as ListData. This will be in usercontrol

```
public string ListData { get; set; }
```

Assign string with comma separator to this property

```
<uc1:MyListControl ID="MyListControl1" runat="server" ListData="ABC,XYZ" />
```

You can parse this string to List in page_load of usercontrol.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListData))
        {
            MyList = ListData.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Now you can use this MyList as list populated with data

Comment: There must be a better way.